# Determine width of rim to match tyre

Tags: tire, rims

I need some 5 ray rims but the ones I find on the internet are way too expensive, so I decided to "roll my own" by creating a 3D model and having it machined from a piece of aluminum.

I've chosen to go with 20x2.125, or roughly 500mm in diameter and 50mm in width, tires for my rim. I'm looking at the [nominal section widths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_5775#Nominal_section_widths) of the standard and for this size tire I see that a size of `21C, 23C, 25C` rim is required. Nowhere is mentioned what `C` stands for tho. I assume it's from `crotched` but I'd like a word of comfort on that. So basically this means that my rim's inner width (the one labeled 19 [here](https://velosiped.bg/media/catalog/product/cache/6a4eceea2f437fa246e0db35845b3a0e/c/r/crosser_20_-x2_section_.jpg)) must be between 21 and 25 millimeters?

Comment: [This chart](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width) isn't perfect, but it's about as good as you can hope for.  A 50mm tire would fit a rim about 23mm wide (inside measurement).  [This diagram](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#isoetrto) explains rim diameters about as well as anyone can.

Comment: @DanielRHicks So basically my assumptions were correct. I'm confused tho by your second link. In the table there it says 20 inch rims are 451 mm, and 20 inch is 508 mm?

Comment: I cannot believe that having wheels machined from a 20x20x2.125" billet is cheaper than buying mass produced ones.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus well they sell for upwards of $100. In my case I need 4 so thats $400 total in the cheapest case. Now the material needed to make those costs less than $10, how much would they charge me to load a file and watch the machine cut it? I've spoken with a company which offers cnc services and they said they need the model to give me a price so I'm working on it now.

Comment: 20 inch rims are 451mm, except the Schwinn rims, which are 419.  There are 4 different diameters for "24 inch" rims.  The "system" used prior to the ISO system was insane.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I don't get it, `20 x 25.4 = 508`, how is it 451?

Comment: Are you trying to multiply the inch tire diameter and the mm tire width to get the ISO bead circle diameter??  That's not how it works.

Comment: Oh, and 20 x 1.5 rims have a 406mm diameter.  It's crazy.  Your best bet is to pick the tire you want, read it's ISO dimensions off the sidewall, and ignore the inch measurements completely.

Comment: (The "c" suffix refers to the old French metric scheme, primarily seen for "700" road tires.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'm trying to figure out the rim's outer diameter, which is supposedly 20 inches which is 508 millimeters, I don't get how it works, why is it so confusing :/ If I design my rim to be 508 millimeters in diameter it looks like I wouldn't find a tire to fit, doh!

Comment: You have to understand that the "inch" values are pure fiction.  They supposedly refer to the *outer* diameter of the tire (not the bead circle diameter), and often are not even that.  A 27 inch tire has a larger BCD than a 29 inch tire.

Comment: Review the Sheldon Brown web site I linked to (both links are the same page, just different spots).  It will eventually begin to make sense.

Comment: @DanielRHicks guess my best bet is to look at the millimeter values then and make my rim 451mm, adding tire height will have it somewhere around 500mm which is my required wheel diameter. Thank you  for your time, sir!

Comment: @php_nub_qq I think your estimate of metal cost is way off. See here: https://www.metalsdepot.com/aluminum-products/6061-aluminum-sheet-plate 2.5" x 1' x 1' 6061 plate is over $400, and that's smaller than you need.

Comment: As I said, pick a tire you like, then read the ISO numbers off the sidewall and use those to dimension your rims.

Comment: This is fascinating - can you add in some background why you need those specific wheels?  Why do you need four?   Have you priced in all the hub/spoke costs as well for your build ?

Comment: @Criggie I'm building a mini electromobile. I figured spoke rims and hubs are not strong enough as it will weigh around 250kg with load + I really want it to look nice, and spoke rims are not a particularly good suit for a "car". I'm going buy bearings that are rated for my required weight and build custom flanges to mount rotors for disk brakes. It sure will be a lot of work but hey I signed up for it :D

Comment: *creating a 3D model and having it machined from a piece of aluminum* Spoked rims aren't just chunks of aluminum machined to shape. [There's actually a lot of engineering the goes into making good rims.](https://www.dtswiss.com/en/technology/wheel-technology/) Or even **safe** rims.  Out of one chunk of aluminum, how are you planning on making sure the spoke holes are strong enough not to crack?  The sidewalls are hard enough not to wear away under brake pads, are not brittle, but still strong and tough enough not to shatter when you hit a bump?  Solid wheels have similar concerns.

Comment: But as others have said, fascinating.  Just be careful and test your wheels before you put yourself in potential danger.  For example, what happens if you're in a sharp turn, going fast, and lock up your brakes?  That will put a *lot* of sideways force on the front wheels, assuming you're using a "standard" four-wheel configuration with front-wheel steering for your vehicle.  A thin aluminum disk wheel might very well collapse sideways under such a load.  When you solve that problem, add in hitting a moderate pavement bump in the middle of that maneuver.

Comment: I'm not sure if Engineering or Mechanics is the better stack to ask.   Its very interesting for sure.

Comment: I am skeptical of the strength of a machined rim.  I have to believe that some of the strength of one-piece auto rims comes from them having been cast/forged, and the stress-equalizing effects that result.

Comment: Wow thank you guys for the advice and resources, extremely helpful !!!

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are most likely right, but under those extreme conditions I am skeptical *any* bicycle wheel will survive with a 200kg load. Although your point is valid, steering angles at higher speeds are typically lower (aside that the car will hardly go faster than 40km/h by my calculations), so I must be really doing some hard cornering and at the same time stopping for this to occur. Not saying it's impossible but will surely bear that in mind. I'm doing this more as an entertainment project and just maybe if something comes out of it I can use it for going to the grocery store :D

Comment: @DanielRHicks hey, worst case scenario, I can just use the machined one as a model for a cast, right? :D

Comment: After you duct-tape the pieces back together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the inside width of the rim should be at least half the tire width and can be almost as wide as the tire itself. So for a 50-622 tire anything between 25 (a bit less would probably still be okay) and 50mm should work.

The problem with wide tires in narrow rims is that the tire will be unstable in corners at low pressure and can break the rim at very high pressures. I’ve ridden 35mm cyclocross tires inflated to less than 2 bar on 13mm rims and  wouldn’t recommend it.

Comment: I will surely follow Daniel Hicks' advice though, to first find tires.